# How to access validation accuracy of a model after fit Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get the average accuracy of multiple trainings of my simple image recognition model. I wanted to run it 10ish times in a for function and update my avg_accuracy variable after every `model.summary()

```
avg_accuracy = 0.0

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=train_batches, validation_data=valid_batches, epochs=1, verbose=2, batch_size=16)


test_labels = test_batches.classes
predictions = model.predict(x=test_batches, verbose=0)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`model.evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) method to get the loss and metrics values established in your model in test mode. You need to pass both the test samples and the labels in order to let the model compare the prediction with the expected labels:

```
model.evaluate(x=test_batches, y=test_labels, verbose=2)
```